# Find subspace $U \cap (V+W)$

Tags: linear-algebra

In linear space X where $\dim X = 6$ there are $3$ linear subspaces $U$,$V$,$W$ such that: 
$$\dim U = 2 $$
$$U  \cap  V = U  \cap W = \left\{ 0 \right\} $$
Agree/disagree with this statement:
$$U \cap (V+W) = \left\{ 0 \right\}$$

### My try

I was convinced that it is $\left\{ 0 \right\}$ because
$$V+W = span( \text{all_vectors_from_v},\text{all_vectors_from_w})$$ so if
$$ U  \cap  V = U  \cap W = \left\{ 0 \right\}$$
then exactly $$U \cap (V+W) = \left\{ 0 \right\}$$ is true. But in book the correct answer is False...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4,x_5$ be linearly independent. Take $U=span(x_1,x_2),V=span(x_1+x_4,x_5), W=span(x_1-x_4,x_5)$. Verify that the hypothesis is satisfied but $x_1 \in U \cap (V+W)$.

Comment: ahhh, nice counter example. Thanks!

Comment: You just need three linearly independent vectors, $x_1,x_2,x_3$, with $U=\operatorname{span}(x_1,x_2)$, $V=\operatorname{span}(x_1+x_3)$ and $W=\operatorname{span}(x_1-x_3)$.

Comment: @egreg Sure. I showered a lot of generosity on myself!